# Select distinct using mysqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to `select distinct` from mysql database using mysqli `prepared statements`.

however, when I run my code, I get no error at all but I cannot get the results from the mysql database either!

this is my mysqli `prepared statement`:

```
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `title`, `url` FROM `$Pages`");
echo $storePages;
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title, $url);
$stmt->store_result();
while($line=$stmt->fetch()){
    $tvalue[] = $line;
     }
```

but This code works and i do not want to use it as it is not mysqli prepared statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT title, url FROM $Pages";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $tvalue[] = $line;
    }
```

could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stmt->fetch()` does not return the row fetched, it only returns **true**, **false**, or **null**. Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

The results are stored in the variables you told it to use in `$stmt->bind_result()`.

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title, $url);
$stmt->store_result();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $tvalue[] = array('title'=>$title, 'url'=>$url);
}
```

If you have mysqlnd installed (which should be [enabled by default since PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php)), it would be simpler for your case to `fetch_all()`. That way you don't need `bind_result()`, nor do you need to loop over rows:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$tvalue = $result->fetch_all();
```

Comment: I got a downvote. Downvoter, can you offer a comment on why you think this answer is wrong? Perhaps I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Always check your return values. Always.

```
if( ! $stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `title`, `url` FROM `$Pages`") ) {
  die( $db_conx->error );
}
echo $storePages;
if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
  die( $stmt->error );
}
$stmt->bind_result($title, $url);
$stmt->store_result();

while($line = $stmt->fetch()){
  $tvalue[] = $line;
}
```

Comment: what does this suppose to do? I get nothing (no errors) on my page and i get no results from mysql database either running this code.